# How to get rid of a phantom folder in OS X?

Tags: macos, command-line, terminal

I have a weird folder in my home directory. It's called "..Copied!" This name probably comes from an unfortunate period of time when I had overridden `pwd` in my bash profile. I learned my lesson and want to get rid of this file now, but it's not accessible, even though it shows up when I search for it using locate.

[image: (It looks likenode.js source files were copied there.)]

And I can certainly see it with `ls .` and then double tabbing.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Since you can use `bash` tab completion to `ls` the file, you can definitely use something like  `rm -r ..Copied\!` to remove it.

If you were asked any questions by rm, you have to use the `-f` option or `chmod -R` first.

(Note that you must escape the "!" character as otherwise it's expanded to a task pid.)

Comment: Not working for me. It fails silently without any error messages. It doesn't autocomplete when I try from `rm -r` so apparently that command cannot see the folder...but `ls .` does?

Comment: AFAIK, `rm` will not fail silently. It should always tell you what went wrong. If you can't use tab completion, why not manually copy and paste the path (and do the escaping).